# How do I turn off request validation in MVC3?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, requestvalidationmode

I've installed the RC1 release of **MVC 3** and I'm using Entity Framework 4 for my model.

NOTE: I had this working just fine in MVC2, but MVC3 changed how this works.

I've read the following articles and was able to get to the code below...

- [Granular Request Validation in ASP.NET MVC 3](https://web.archive.org/web/20150629231249/http://blogs.msdn.com:80/b/marcinon/archive/2010/11/09/mvc3-granular-request-validation-update.aspx)
- [Announcing the ASP.NET MVC 3 Release Candidate](https://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/announcing-the-asp-net-mvc-3-release-candidate)
- [Validation with the Data Annotation Validators](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/mvc/overview/older-versions-1/models-data/validation-with-the-data-annotation-validators-cs)

Here's my EF4 Meta Data model...

```
[MetadataType(typeof(ArticleMetaData))]
partial class Article
{
}

public class ArticleMetaData
{
    [SkipRequestValidation()]
    public string Body { get; set; }
}
```

And here's a simplified version of my controller action...

```
[HttpPost]
[Authorize(Roles = "Admin")]
[ValidateInput(false)]
public ActionResult Edit(string id, FormCollection values)
{
    Article article;
    article = GetArticle(id);
    UpdateModel(article);
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        Repository.SaveChanges();
        return RedirectToAction("Article", new { id = article.Slug });
    }
    return View(article);
}
```

What am I doing wrong? Is there a better pattern for me to be following?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try to remove `[ValidateInput(false)]` and change `FormCollection` to `Article`.

Here works fine that way...

Comment: That worked, thanks. As a note, I am not passing all the values for the object in from the form. For others in a similar situation, the only thing I changed from my original code was I made Article the only parameter. I am still loading the Article from the database and calling UpdateModel on it.